# Отсутствует света от area light

Tags: unity3d

Делал сперва игру без background'а, просто использовал черный фон. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И подсветка (area light) нормально работалf, а как добавил background (Grid), свет сразу же пропал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за "Bg (Grid)"?

Comment: это background, он у меня на tile'ах сделан. Я изменил текст.

Comment: Все равно мало информации, как сделан этот бэк из тайлов - важно

Comment: делал по этому примеру https://habr.com/ru/post/412765/